# Create Array Inside Foreach Loop

Tags: php, arrays

How to put these codes in a foreach loop?

```
    $item1_details = array(
        'id' => 'a1',
        'price' => 18000,
        'quantity' => 3,
        'name' => "Apple"
    );


    $item2_details = array(
        'id' => 'a2',
        'price' => 20000,
        'quantity' => 2,
        'name' => "Orange"
    );
```

Then the array above will be saved in a variable. It's an array. And, yes, I have no idea how to do a loop inside array. So please help me for this too.

```
    $item_details = array ($item1_details, $item2_details);
```

Thus, I have to questions. First, how to create an array inside a foreach loop. Second, How to loop inside an array.

Comment: What are your expecting output?

Answer (score 0):

You don't put a loop inside an array, you push onto the array in a loop.

```
$item_details = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $item_details[] = $item1_details;
    $item_details[] = $item2_details;
}
```

This will make an array with 10 alternating copies of `$item1_details` and `$item2_details`.

You mentioned a `foreach` loop, but that's for looping over an array that already exists. You didn't show any array to loop over, so I'm not sure how it applies in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_values` with `array_merge`

```
$f = array_merge(array_values($item1_details), array_values($item2_details));
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/fDM3N